# http_build_query ignore one key

Tags: php, query-string

I've a URL which becomes a query string with the `http_build_query` function.

But I have a parameter`timestamp` which I cannot edit. And `&times` becomes a multiplication sign `x`.

Is there a workaround for this?

This is my array which gets passed to the `http_build_query` function.

```
$parameters =   array(
            "transaction_id"=>uniqid("FF-"),
            "timestamp"=> time(),
            "order_total"=>$_SESSION['total_price'],
            "order_total_with_vat"=>$_SESSION['total_price'] * 1.21,
            "order_vat"=>"21",
            "payment_method"=>"ideal",
            "payment_status"=>"1",
            "customer_name"=>$_SESSION['customer_data']['naam'],
            "customer_address"=>$_SESSION['customer_data']['address'],
            "customer_city"=>$_SESSION['customer_data']['city'],
            "customer_zipcode"=>$_SESSION['customer_data']['zipcode'],
            "customer_country"=>$_SESSION['customer_data']['country'],
            "customer_email"=>$_SESSION['customer_data']['email'],
            "customer_telephone"=>$_SESSION['customer_data']['telephone'],
        );
```

Output of url:

```
http://somedomain/subdir/someapi/order?transaction_id=FF-58e2451c5aea9×tamp=1491223836&order_total=156695&order_total_with_vat=189600.95&order_vat=21&payment_method=ideal&payment_status=1&customer_name=t&customer_address=t&customer_city=t&customer_zipcode=t&customer_country=t&customer_email=t%40t&customer_telephone=t&product%5B0%5D=5&product%5B1%5D=5&product%5B2%5D=5&product%5B3%5D=5&product%5B4%5D=5&product%5B5%5D=5&product%5B6%5D=5
```

Preferred output:

```
http://somedomain/subdir/someapi/order?transaction_id=FF-58e2451c5aea9&timestamp=1491223836&order_total=156695&order_total_with_vat=189600.95&order_vat=21&payment_method=ideal&payment_status=1&customer_name=t&customer_address=t&customer_city=t&customer_zipcode=t&customer_country=t&customer_email=t%40t&customer_telephone=t&product%5B0%5D=5&product%5B1%5D=5&product%5B2%5D=5&product%5B3%5D=5&product%5B4%5D=5&product%5B5%5D=5&product%5B6%5D=5
```

`http_build_query` function:

```
case 'POST':
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    $url    .= '?' . http_build_query( $parameters );
    break;
```

Comment: can you please provide sample code, an example, and desired output

Comment: You might be able to unset the key before passing it in. Or copy the array, unset the key, and pass it in.

Comment: What have you tried? Provide some code.

Comment: can you also show the code you're using `http_build_query` to make the url

Comment: See updated question

Comment: use `Content-Type: text/plain` header for var_dumps

Comment: It's just a display issue in browser but your curl data will go just like what you have shown in your preffered output , no need to add anything extra just hit and go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Novice was right, he commented on my question:

> 

It's just a display issue in browser but your curl data will go just like what you have shown in your preferred output , no need to add anything extra just hit and go! – Novice

When I checked the apache access.log I could see the preferred query string posted.

Answer (score 5):

Currently it is working correctly.  The issue is that when you echo your URL the sequence `&times` will make your browser replace it with the multiplication symbol `x`.  To echo it and show the correct way in the browser try this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($url);
```

This will display the desired URL.